# Break lines in powershell array and then convert it to html?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I swear I've been searching a lot and still haven't found any solution to this thing.
What I do is basically converting arrays to HTML but I can't find any way to break the words of the array in new lines.

For example:

```
$Member.ExpireOn=((Invoke-SqliteQuery -SQLiteConnection $C -Query "SELECT expireon FROM exceptions_test WHERE (identity='$User')").ExpireOn -join "`r`n")
```

$Member.ExpireOn is basically this:

```
31/01/2019 00:00:00 31/03/2019 00:00:00 31/03/2019 00:00:00
```

so even if I join it with `-join "`r`n"` or with `<br>` I can't find any way to have a line for each element in the array.
I need to do it because after that I print the whole array in a HTML file and this is what I get:

[image]

instead of having a `<br>` between those words.
Hopefully somebody can help me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> even if I join it with `` -join "`r`n" ``

Whitespace in HTML is insignificant, so you cannot force line breaks this way; they will show in the HTML *markup* (source code), but not *when rendered*.

> or with `<br>`

The problem is that **[`ConvertTo-Html`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-html)** - which I assume you're using - ***escapes* any HTML markup in the input objects' property values** (it assumes you want to use the values verbatim), so **you cannot pass `<br>` through** in order to make a single table cell use multiple line - you'll see *literal* `<br>` strings in the table, because `ConvertTo-Html` has escaped them as `&lt;br&gt;`.

---

A **quick and dirty workaround** would be to manually convert the escaped `<br>` elements back to their HTML form:

```
# Sample input objects
$o = [pscustomobject] @{
  Foo = 'Cert A'
  # Join the array elements with <br>
  ExpireOn = (Get-Date), (Get-date).AddDays(1) -join '<br>'
}, [pscustomobject] @{
  Foo = 'Cert B'
  ExpireOn = (Get-Date).AddDays(2), (Get-date).AddDays(3) -join '<br>'
}

# Convert *escaped* <br> elements back to literal '<br>'
# NOTE: This will replace *all* instances of '&lt;br&gt;' in the 
#       document text, wherever it may occur.
($o | ConvertTo-Html) -replace '&lt;br&gt;', '<br>'
```

This yields the following, showing that the `<br>` was effectively passed through, which should make the input date values render on individual lines:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML TABLE</title>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>Foo</th><th>ExpireOn</th></tr>
<!-- Note the <br> elements -->
<tr><td>Cert A</td><td>2/5/2020 12:51:45 PM<br>2/6/2020 12:51:45 PM</td></tr>
<tr><td>Cert B</td><td>2/7/2020 12:51:45 PM<br>2/8/2020 12:51:45 PM</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

In Chrome on my Mac, this renders as follows:

[image]

---

If you need a **more robust solution**, you'll have to **use an HTML parser** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60658511/45375).