# How to parse HTML table with Powershell Core 7?

Tags: html, powershell, powershell-core

I have the following code:

```
    $html = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
    $source = Get-Content -Path $FilePath -Raw
    try
    {
        $html.IHTMLDocument2_write($source) 2> $null
    }
    catch
    {
        $encoded = [Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($source)
        $html.write($encoded)
    }
    $t = $html.getElementsByTagName("table") | Where-Object {
        $cells = $_.tBodies[0].rows[0].cells
        $cells[0].innerText -eq "Name" -and
        $cells[1].innerText -eq "Description" -and
        $cells[2].innerText -eq "Default Value" -and
        $cells[3].innerText -eq "Release"
    }
```

The code works fine on Windows Powershell 5.1, but on Powershell Core 7 `$_.tBodies[0].rows` returns null.

So, how does one access the rows of an HTML table in PS 7?

Comment: See also: [Extracting HTML table as CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67162906/1701026)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**PowerShell (Core)**, as of 7.4, **does *not* come with a built-in HTML parser** - and this **may never change**.

You must rely on a **third-party solution**, such as the **[`PSParseHTML` module](https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSParseHTML)** that wraps the **[HTML Agility Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/)**,<sup>[1]</sup> and the **[AngleSharp library](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp)**. The former is used by default, the latter requires opt-in `-Engine AngleSharp`; as for their respective **DOMs (object models)**:

- The **HTML Agility Pack**, which is used by default, works differently than the Internet Explorer-based one available in Windows PowerShell; it is ***similar* to the XML DOM provided by the standard [`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument) type (`[xml]`)**<sup>[2]</sup>; see [the documentation](https://html-agility-pack.net/manipulation) and the sample code below.
- **AngleSharp**, which requires opt-in via `-Engine AngleSharp`, is built upon the official W3C specification and therefore provides a **HTML DOM as available in web browsers**. Notably, this means that its `.QuerySelector()` and `.QuerySelectorAll()` methods can be used with the usual [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77447338/45375) for an example of its use.

---

**Self-contained sample code** that uses the **HTML Agility Pack engine**:

```bash
# Install the module on demand
If (-not (Get-Module -ErrorAction Ignore -ListAvailable PSParseHTML)) {
  Write-Verbose "Installing PSParseHTML module for the current user..."
  Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser PSParseHTML -ErrorAction Stop
}

# Create a sample HTML file with a table with 2 columns.
Get-Item $HOME | Select-Object Name, Mode | ConvertTo-Html > sample.html

# Parse the HTML file into an HTML DOM.
$htmlDom = Get-Content -Raw sample.html | ConvertFrom-Html

# Find a specific table by its column names, using an XPath
# query to iterate over all tables.
$table = $htmlDom.SelectNodes('//table') | Where-Object {
  $headerRow = $_.Element('tr') # or $tbl.Elements('tr')[0]
  # Filter by column names
  $headerRow.ChildNodes[0].InnerText -eq 'Name' -and 
    $headerRow.ChildNodes[1].InnerText -eq 'Mode'
}

# Print the table's HTML text.
$table.InnerHtml

# Extract the first data row's first column value.
# Note: @(...) is required around .Elements() for indexing to work.
@($table.Elements('tr'))[1].ChildNodes[0].InnerText
```

---

A **Windows-only alternative** is to use the **`HTMLFile` COM object**, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71855426/45375), and as used in your own attempt - I'm unclear on why it didn't work in your specific case.

---

<sup>[1] Note that this answer originally built on a different PowerShell wrapper module for the HTML Agility Pack, [`PowerHTML`](https://github.com/JustinGrote/PowerHTML) - however, the `PSParseHTML` is more actively maintained.</sup>

<sup>[2] Notably with respect to supporting XPath queries via the `.SelectSingleNode()` and `.SelectNodes()` methods, exposing child nodes via a `.ChildNodes` collection, and providing `.InnerHtml` / `.OuterHtml` / `.InnerText` properties. Instead of an *indexer* that supports child element names, methods `.Element(<name>)` and `.Elements(<name>)` are provided.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I used the answer above for my solution. I installed PowerHTML.
I wanted to extract the datatable from https://www.dicomlibrary.com/dicom/dicom-tags/ and convert them.

From this:

`<tr><td>(0002,0000)</td><td>UL</td><td>File Meta Information Group Length</td><td></td></tr>`

To this:

`{"00020000", "ULFile Meta Information Group Length"}`

```
$page = Invoke-WebRequest https://www.dicomlibrary.com/dicom/dicom-tags/
$htmldom = ConvertFrom-Html $page
$table = $htmlDom.SelectNodes('//table') | Where-Object {
  $headerRow = $_.Element('tr') # or $tbl.Elements('tr')[0]
  # Filter by column names
  $headerRow.ChildNodes[0].InnerText -eq 'Tag' 
}

foreach ($row in $table.SelectNodes('tr'))
 {$a = $row.SelectSingleNode('td[1]').innerText.Trim()  -replace "`n|`r|\s+", " " -replace "\(",'{"' -replace ",","" -replace "\)",'",'
 $c = $row.SelectSingleNode('td[3]').innerText.Trim() -replace "`n|`r|\s+", " "
 $b=$row.seletSingleNode('td[2]').innerText.Trim() -replace "`n|`r|\s+", ""; $c = '"'+$b+$c+'"},'
 $row = New-Object -TypeName psobject
     $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Tag -Value $a
     $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Value -Value $c

     [array]$data += $row
}

$data | Out-File c:\scripts\dd.txt
```