# Regex non capturing group

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-4.0

Regex Experts.
I need some help to capture the IP address and its status from the below HTML string.

```
$html = "<div><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Active Zone : BW Zone 1[1], &nbsp;&nbsp;VIP = 192.168.254.10</div>

<div><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href=https://192.168.254.10/checkGlobalReplicationTier>https://192.168.254.10/checkGlobalReplicationTier</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;[ACTIVE]</div>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href=https://192.168.254.10/checkReplication>https://192.168.254.10/checkReplication</a></div>
<div><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href=https://192.168.254.11/checkGlobalReplicationTier>https://192.168.254.11/checkGlobalReplicationTier</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;[STANDBY]</div>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href=https://192.168.254.11/checkReplication>https://192.168.254.11/checkReplication</a></div>
<div><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Local Zones:</div>
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; LC Zone 3[3], &nbsp;&nbsp;VIP = 192.168.254.13
<div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href=https://192.168.254.13/checkReplication>https://192.168.254.13/checkReplication</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;[ACTIVE]</div>"
```

```
[regex]::matches($html, '((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})((?s).*?)((?<=\[)[A-z]*(?=\]))').value
```

The above regex is able to get the IP and Status.. but i want to omit everything in-between the IP and Status. How do i do this with non capturing regex.

```
192.168.254.10  Active
192.168.254.11  Standby
192.168.254.13  Active
```

Comment: Do you mean non capturing as in capture groups or non matching in the regex match? if you meant non capturing groups then all you have to do is add `?:` to the third capturing group in your expression. It would become: `((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(?:(?s).*?)((?<=\[)[A-z]*(?=\]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, consider [iRon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71855426/45375) for robust HTML parsing with a dedicated parser.

> How do i do this with non capturing regex.

You can't, because in order to exclude parts of the matching span of text you'd need look-around assertions (such as the negative look-behind assertions in your attempt, e.g. `(?<=\[)`), but these in turn prevent you from *consuming* the unwanted parts of the span.

Instead, use two capture groups and access them as follows:

```
[regex]::Matches(
  $html, 
  '(?s)((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}).+?\[([A-Z]+)\]'
 ) | ForEach-Object { 
   [pscustomobject] @{ 
     Ip = $_.Groups[1].Value
     Status = $_.Groups[2].Value
   } 
 }
```

This results in the following display output:

```
Ip             Status
--             ------
192.168.254.10 ACTIVE
192.168.254.11 STANDBY
192.168.254.13 ACTIVE
```

Answer (score 3):

It is generally [a bad idea to attempt to parse HTML with regular expressions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/).
Instead use a dedicated HTML parser as the [**HtmlDocument** class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) (and the [**Uri** class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.uri) for uri's).

**Example**

```
function ParseHtml($String) {
    $Unicode = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($String)
    $Html = New-Object -Com 'HTMLFile'
    if ($Html.PSObject.Methods.Name -Contains 'IHTMLDocument2_Write') {
        $Html.IHTMLDocument2_Write($Unicode)
    } 
    else {
        $Html.write($Unicode)
    }
    $Html.Close()
    $Html
}

$Document = ParseHtml $Html
$Document.getElementsByTagName('div') |ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.lastChild.nodeValue -match '\[(?<Status>ACTIVE|STANDBY)\]') {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Ip     = ([Uri]$($_.getElementsByTagName('a')).href).Host
            Status = $Matches.Status
        }
    }
}
```

```
Ip             Status
--             ------
192.168.254.10 ACTIVE
192.168.254.11 STANDBY
192.168.254.13 ACTIVE
```