# What am I doing wrong with this regex in PowerShell?

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to use this code to scrape a web page with regex in PowerShell:

```
$webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$data = $webClient.downloadstring($url)
$h1Tag = [regex] '(?i)(?<=<h1 class="mb-0 mb-lg-1 svelte-jcq9ad">)([\S\s]*?)(?=<\/h1>)'
$h1 = $h1Tag.Match($data).value.trim()
```

Sample text to search:

```
 <div>
     <h1 class="mb-0 mb-lg-1 svelte-jcq9ad">AdBlock — best ad blocker</h1>
     <h2 class="mb-2 svelte-jcq9ad">Block ads and pop-ups on YouTube, Facebook, Twitch, and your favorite websites.</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

It correctly returns **AdBlock - best ad blocker** when I test the regex expression on a couple of regex test sites, but in PowerShell $h1 is always empty.  What am I missing?

Edit: I updated $title to $h1 in my question.  $title was a typo on my part - $h1 is what I should have said.

Comment: You could treat that as xml if the extra </div> weren't there.  `[xml]$xml = cat file.html; $xml.div.h1.'#text'`

Comment: Using a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to peek and poke in a structured string might give unexpected and greedy results. As [suggested before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71855426/1701026), it is generally [a bad idea to attempt to parse HTML with regular expressions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/).
Instead use a dedicated HTML parser as the [**HtmlDocument** class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72507549/1701026

Comment: Thanks for fixing the `$title` typo, but the other point still applies: with the sample input given, your code works as expected. Try to find a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$data = '<div>
     <h1 class="mb-0 mb-lg-1 svelte-jcq9ad">AdBlock — best ad blocker</h1>
     <h2 class="mb-2 svelte-jcq9ad">Block ads and pop-ups on YouTube, Facebook, Twitch, and your favorite websites.</h2>
  </div>
</div>'

$null = $data -match("AdBlock — best ad blocker")
$h1 = $Matches.Values
```

Comment: This doesn't use the OP's regex and is otherwise just a reformulation of the OP's own attempt based on using the `-match` operator instead of the `Regex.Match()` .NET API. While showing `-match` as a PowerShell-idiomatic alternative is a good idea in general, it can't be expected to make a difference here. Also, it's best to avoid `(...)` (pseudo method syntax) with PowerShell operators, and it's better to use _single_-quoted strings for regexes. -> `-match 'AdBlock — best ad blocker'`

Answer (score 0):

First things first:

- It's best to use a dedicated HTML parser if possible, which enables a more robust solution than a regex-based one, which is invariably brittle - see iRon's comment on the question.

---

As noted, your regex *does* work with your sample input, implying that the sample input isn't representative of your actual problem.

The following *may* solve your problem, because it uses a **more flexible reformulation of your regex**, and it also **showcases the idiomatic way to perform a single regex match in PowerShell**, using the **[`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch)**:

```bash
$data = '<div>
     <h1 class="mb-0 mb-lg-1 svelte-jcq9ad">AdBlock — best ad blocker</h1>
     <h2 class="mb-2 svelte-jcq9ad">Block ads and pop-ups on YouTube, Facebook, Twitch, and your favorite websites.</h2>
  </div>
</div>'

$h1 = 
  if ($data -match '(?s)(?<=<h1\s+class=[''"]mb-0\s+mb-lg-1\s+svelte-jcq9ad[''"]\s*>)(.*?)(?=</\s*h1>)') {
    # Output the trimmed form of the match, which is stored in entry 0
    # of the automatic $Matches variable.
    $Matches[0].Trim()
  }

# Output the result.
$h1
```

Note:

- `-match` is case-insensitive *by default* (as are *all* text-relevant PowerShell operators), so there's no need for the `(?i)` inline option.
- However inline option `(?s)` was added, so as to allow `.` to match *newlines* too, obviating the need for the `[\s\S]` workaround.
- `/` never needs escaping (as `\/`) in PowerShell, given that regexes are specified as normal *string literals* (inside of which `/` has no special meaning).
- The regex has been made more flexible with respect to whitespace (mandatory whitespace is represented as `\s+`, optional one as `\s*`, and quoting characters (both `'` and `"` are matched).
- For a detailed explanation and the ability to experiment with the regex, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/bKS78Z/3).
  Note: The linked page uses C# string syntax, but the string content is identical to the one above (and both PowerShell and C# use the .NET regex engine).