Regular Expression to extract Urls from file
I am currently working on a regular expression to extract urls from a file. here is what I have come up with so far:
(http|https)://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)*?(/(\w|\.)*)*

however the issue is that sometimes the urls in the file are not separated from each other, so you might have a string like
http://www.example.com/page1/page2/downloadshttps://example2.com/page1/page2

and so the \w* will continue matching all the way to the ":" character, making it impossible to match https://example2.com
How do I achieve it that the regular expression cuts off before the new "http|https" starts?
I have attempted negative look-ahead (?!(html)), but I am not quite sure where to place it.
As for the programming language I am working with PowerShell.

How did the urls get into the file in that shape? It seems they come from somewhere and have already been processes (badly).

This isn't really possible to solve robustly. That's a valid single URL, as well as two URLs side by side.

And even if you decide that https:// is not allowed in the path part of a URL, doing this with a regular expression will be tricky.

Did you try to split the lines at http or https ?

A simpler version of (http|https) is https?.

You can also outsource it to an LLM is for some reason you are unable to split the string by http/https.


This solution isn't fully robust, but may be good enough in practice:
# Sample file content string.
$fileContent =  @'
one 
     http://www.example.com/page1/page2/downloadshttps://example2.com/page1/page2 

two 
     https://example.org
three
'@

# ->
#  @(
#     'http://www.example.com/page1/page2/downloads', 
#     'https://example2.com/page1/page2', 
#     'https://example.org'
#  )
[regex]::Matches(
  $fileContent,
  'https?://(?:\S+(?=https?://)|\S+)'
).Value


For an explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see this regex101.com page; the gist is to use a positive lookahead assertion ((?=...)) to detect when the next URL starts.

For brevity, the simplistic assumption is made that http:// or https:// followed by any non-empty run of non-whitespace characters (\S) constitutes a URL (but you should be able to replace the two instances of \S+ with more sophisticated patterns, as in your own attempt); also, http:// or https:// is interpreted as the start of a URL when preceded by any character, even if that character isn't the end of a previous URL.



Given the feedback, I have concluded that this task is not feasible with regex. Instead a string split on "https" was implemented first before using the regex to "clean up" the urls
thank you @hc_dev for the suggestion

While a fully robust regex solution may not be possible, one that may work well enough in practice is (my initial attempt was flawed, but I've resurrected the answer in corrected form).

You didn't disclose in your question what kind of file you are extracting from. By narrowing the possible solutions to just using a regular expression you appearently created a kind of XY problem. If at the other hand, the file is structured (as e.g. html), you probably better of with using a much robuster parser instead, see e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72507549/1701026
