# powershell invoke-webrequest does not work but invoke-restmethod works

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest, invoke-restmethod

I want to get the content of a web page and when I use

`$web = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://inkscape.org/"`
I will get the content but when I use

`$web = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://inkscape.org/"`
I won't get anything why it happens?? and what is the difference exactly ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, for *plain-text* or *HTML* response bodies, the relationship between the (older) [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) cmdlet and the [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) cmdlet is as follows with the respect to the default `GET` method:

```
# -UseBasicParsing is only needed in *Windows PowerShell*.
(Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://inkscape.org/").Content
```

is the same as:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://inkscape.org/"
```

That is:

- `Invoke-WebRequest` returns a *response object* whose `.Content` property contains the *body* of the response, *always as text* (except if you save the raw body to a *file* with `-OutFile`).

  - For HTML response bodies, *Windows PowerShell* attempts to also parse the HTML text into an HTML DOM, surfaced via the `.ParsedHTML` property, using the obsolete *Internet Explorer*. `-UseBasicParsing` suppresses this. This switch has no effect in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, which fundamentally doesn't support parsing HTML, requiring third-party solutions (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60658511/45375) for an example) or - on Windows only - a COM-based solution (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71855426/45375)).
- `Invoke-RestMethod` *directly* returns the response *body* (only).

  - Additionally, if the target site indicates that XML or JSON data is being returned, `Invoke-RestMethod` doesn't return the body as *text*, but automatically parses it into an `[xml]` instance / `[System.Xml.XmlElement]` instances (for RSS / Atom feeds) or a `[pscustomobject]` graph (`ConvertFrom-Json` is *built in*, so to speak).
  - Even in the absence of a known response data format, PowerShell *tries* to parse the response body, first as XML, then as JSON; if all attempts fail, plain text (a `[string]` instance) is returned.
  - Even for `text/html` responses an attempt is made to parse them *as XML*. That is, if a page *happens to be* valid XML (which is rare these days), you'll get an `[xml]` instance back; for instance, the very simple HTML5 page at https://httpbin.org/html *happens to be* valid XML (excluding the `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration), whereas HTML5 pages in general are *not*. Thus, 
    `(Invoke-RestMethod https://httpbin.org/html).GetType().FullName` returns `System.Xml.XmlDocument`, i.e. an `[xml]` instance.