# How to work with xpath on strings containing html in Powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I want to extract values from a html document and in another program (ui.vision / selenium) I can do it with xpath statements. I have worked out a whole lot of working xpaths, and now I want to use them in Powershell. I have the string $html containing everything from `<html>` to `</html>` (incl.).

As far as I have researched, I need to have an xml object to use 'Select-Xml' with xpath statements.

In order to convert $html to xml I tried to cast:

```
[xml]$xml = $html
```

as well as

```
 $xml = [xml]$html
```

and I tried to convert:

```
$html = $html | ConvertTo-xml
```

All failed. I think that the html needs to be very well-formatted, but it is not (even if it's perfect html and passes the W3 validator without warnings). It's minified and most attributes lack parentheses.

**So how can I get xpath to work on a string containing a html website?** I am about to resort to regular expressions, but it seems to be a lot of work to translate all the xpath statements.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML** documents (except the XHTML variant, which is rarely seen these days) are ***not* valid XML** and therefore cannot be parsed as such.

A **third-party HTML parsing library** that provides an API that is similar to the  standard [`[xml]` (`System.Xml.XmlDocument`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument) API and therefore includes **XPath support** via methods such as `.SelectNodes()` is the **[HTML Agility Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/)**, for which a PowerShell wrapper, the [`PSParseHTML` module](https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSParseHTML), exists - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60658511/45375) for an example of its use.