# I need to pass a line number from an object

Tags: powershell

```
>$search="<table id="
 $linenumber= Get-Content ".\145039.html" | select-string $search | Select-Object LineNumber

$search="</table>"
$linenumber2= Get-Content ".\145039.html" | select-string $search | Select-Object LineNumber
#$linenumber2


# the list of line numbers to fetch
$linesToFetch = $linenumber[2]..$linenumber2[2]
$currentLine  = 1
$result  = switch -File ".\145039.html" {
    default { if ($linesToFetch -contains $currentLine++) { $_ }}
}

# write to file and also display on screen by using -PassThru
$result | Set-Content -Path ".\excerpt.html" -PassThru



Cannot convert the "@{LineNumber=6189}" value of type              "Selected.Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo" to type "System.Int32".
At line:10 char:1
+ $linesToFetch = $linenumber[2]..$linenumber2[2]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException
```

---

$linenumber and $linenumber2 return values like below but I just need to get the number not the column header.

```
LineNumber
----------
      6015
```

Also, the final version needs to loop through all the html files in a directory not just one static file.

Sorry, there is probably a better way to do this but not sure how.

Thanks in advance!

Did a lot of googling but could not find the right solution.

---

```
Updated code:
     $search1="disconnect-status"
    $linenumber1= Get-Content ".\145039.html" | select-string 
    $search1 
      | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber
    

   $search2="</table>"
    $linenumber2= Get-Content ".\145039.html" | select-string 
    $search2 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber
     


    # the list of line numbers to fetch
      $linesToFetch = $linenumber1[3]..$linenumber2[1]
        $currentLine  = 1
    $result  = switch -File ".\145039.html" {
        default { if ($linesToFetch -contains $currentLine++) { $_ }}
    }

    # write to file and also display on screen by using -PassThru
    $result | Set-Content -Path ".\excerpt.html" -PassThru
_____________________________________________________________
```

Thank you @ mklement0

This now works for one file at a time now I need it go select text from all the HTML files in the directory.

Comment: You should use the "dot notation" to get the desired property of the object `$LineNumber.LineNumber` or `$LineNumber2.LineNumber`

Answer (score 1):

- Your *immediate* problem is that you need to change 
  `Select-Object LineNumber`  (which, due to *positional* parameter binding, is equivalent to 
  `Select-Object -Property LineNumber`) to 
  `Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber`.

  - That is, **you must use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)'s `-ExpandProperty` parameter** in order to only **get the *values* of the input objects' `.LineNumber` properties** - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48807857/45375).
- That said, your approach can be optimized in a number of ways, allowing you to make do with *only* a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement:

```bash
$output = $false; $openTagCount = 0
$result = 
  switch -File .\145039.html {
    '<table id=' {
      if (++$openTagCount -eq 3) { $output = $true } # 3rd block found
      continue
    } 
    '</table>' {
      if ($output) { break } # end of 3rd block -> exit
      continue
    }
    default {
      if ($output) { $_ } # inside 3rd block -> output line
    }
  }
```

Note: This extracts the lines inside the *third* `<table>` element that has an `id` attribute, as implied by your *original* solution attempt; the solution you later edited into the question works differently.

---

Taking a step back:

- It looks like your **input is *HTML*, so you're usually better off using HTML parsing** to handle your input:

  - In *Windows PowerShell* you *may* be able to use [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) relying on the Internet Explorer engine *if present* (it isn't anymore by default in recent Windows versions).
  - In recent versions of Windows and in *PowerShell (Core) (v6+)*, you'll either need `New-Object -Com HTMLFile` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60658511/45375) - or a third-party solution such as  such as the [`PowerHTML` module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PowerHTML) that wraps the [HTML Agility Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60658511/45375).

Comment: Thanks! I edited my code with the -expandproperty and that worked.  I tried your code but can't get that to work.
I need to get only two tables form the html files located in a directory.  I did try to look for an html parser but got stuck.  My dated code works but now I need it to go through many files and put all the results in one file.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @SteveMize; I totally missed that you're parsing HTML, not XML - please see my update re HTML parsers.

Comment: @SteveMize, as for my code: I got confused about what your original code is trying to do; please see my update, which, however, still contradicts your most recent comment: in your original code you're using `[2]`, implying that you want the lines of the _3rd_ table, which is what my code now does. What is the actual intent? As for processing multiple files: once you get the single `switch` statement working, you can simply call it in a loop.