# Parsing HTML With Powershell

Tags: html, powershell, parsing, invoke-webrequest

Still new to powershell, so sorry ahead of time. But I am trying to extract the data highlighted in yellow. But it seems like when the I run the following nothing is happening.

```
$getmeinfo = invoke-webrequest -Uri https://portal.assessor.lacounty.gov/parceldetail/5130020021
$UserHTMLDetails = $getmeinfo.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('div') | Where-Object { $_.className -eq ' col-sm-4 '}
```

Comment: Fundamentally, only _Windows PowerShell_ supports HTML parsing, and only if the Internet Explorer engine is present. If you get no output _and no errors_, the implication is that either `.getElementsByTagName('div')` returns nothing or, more likely, that your `Where-Object` filter doesn't match anything. Looking at your filter: remove the spaces around `col-sm-4`; with simplified syntax, you can try `Where-Object ClassName -eq col-sm-4`

Comment: Check out this thread for parsing tables with PS Core via the PowerHTML module: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60655737/how-to-parse-html-table-with-powershell-core-7